# Docker container not responding

Tags: ruby, docker, sinatra

I am setting up a container manually to create a proper Docker file.

I am starting from bitnami/ruby:latest a container with the following syntax:

```
sudo docker run -p 4567:4567 --name vcaexplorer bitnami/ruby bash
```

The container gets instantiated correctly:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
1ac394d247a4        bitnami/ruby        "/entrypoint.sh bash"   37 minutes ago      Up 37 minutes       3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4567->4567/tcp   vcaexplorer
```

I am downloading the follwoing repo with this syntax:

```
git clone https://github.com/mreferre/vcautils.git /app/vcautils
```

I then start the Sinatra app in the /app/vcautils/lib directory.

It looks like this:

```
bitnami@1ac394d247a4:/app/vcautils/lib$ ruby vcaexplorer.rb 
vcaexplorer.rb:36: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
vcaexplorer.rb:39: warning: class variable access from toplevel
vcaexplorer.rb:40: warning: class variable access from toplevel
vcaexplorer.rb:41: warning: class variable access from toplevel
[2015-09-24 21:42:48] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-09-24 21:42:48] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2015-09-24 21:42:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=255 port=4567
```

when I try to connect to `dockerhost:4567` it gives me a black eye. It says there is nothing there.

I tried to install net-utils in the container and I started the Sinatra app in background (with `&`). It seems to be starting in background but when I run netstat nothing is listed (but the process is there).

The docker host is in good shape because if I try other containers all the internal NATting works fine and I can access the containers from the outside.

Even the app is in good shape as if I start it locally on my laptop with the same command it gives me the same "output" and I can connect to `localhost:4567`

It must be something with the way I am instantiating the container (using bash?)

Thoughts?

Thanks. Massimo.

Comment: I’m not sure how Docker works, but this looks like it’s due to [Sinatra only listening on `localhost` by default in dev mode](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#bind---server-hostname-or-ip-address). Does adding `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` to your app help?

Comment: DANG! That was it! Thanks a ton @matt. There were a couple of things that misled me. 1) when I ran the program in background netstat didn't see anything nor I could wget the home page inside the same container. Now I do see it and I can wget (probably I was doing something wrong yesterday night). 2) I am pushing this app as-is to CloudFoundry and it worked just fine (probably CF does a bit of its magic). Thanks a lot!

Comment: As an additional piece of info, I decided NOT to tweak the program (it may break in other deployments e.g. with CF) so I decided to start the program with `ruby vcaexplorer.rb -o 0.0.0.0` which seems to be doing the same thing. Also, I could also start it with `-p 80` to have it listen on port 80 (port 80 requires root privileges though). Thanks a ton.

Comment: @matt post your answer as an Answer not a comment so the poster can accept it.

Comment: Yes +1 @jpapejr . I was looking for a way to say "right answer" but I couldn't. Matt I'd like to give you credit if you post it properly!